# Django-tables2 subclass error (class attributes not passed to instantiated object)

Tags: python, django, subclass, django-tables2

I'm using django-tables2 and trying to create a new DeleteColumn class:

**tables.py**

```
class DeleteColumn(tables.TemplateColumn):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteColumn, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.template_name='wakemeup/admin/delete_link.html'
        self.verbose_name=''

class SchoolsTable(tables.Table):
    test = DeleteColumn()

    class Meta:
        model = School
```

I keep getting this error, though: `ValueError: A template must be provided`

Am I not creating the class properly?  Why doesn't the `template_name` value specified in the class get passed along when creating a new instance of `DeleteColumn`?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source of `TemplateColumn` (http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_tables2/columns/templatecolumn.html) you'll see that `__init__()` checks for a `template_column` or `template_name` attribute and if neither is found the `ValueError` you mention is thrown.

Now the problem is that you set the `template_name` attribute *after* you have called `super(...).__init__` in your class, thus the `template_name` attribute is empty!

*Edited*

Sorry I didn't check the source code very thouroughly, it's been written in a funny way and doesn't use the attributes. In any case, from what I see now, you'll need to override `__init__` to pass the `template_name` parameter to the parent's init, something like this:

```
class DeleteColumn(tables.TemplateColumn):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This will pass ``template_name`` to the super().__init__ along with any args and kwargs
        super(DeleteColumn, self).__init__(*args, template_name='wakemeup/admin/delete_link.html', **kwargs)
        self.verbose_name=''
```

I hope it works now!

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I tried both of your suggestions and I still get the same `ValueError: A template must be provided` error.  I don't understand why the class isn't passing the attributes when creating the object.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes you are right, the class' been written in a funny way. Please check my answer again after the *edited* tag!

Comment: Interesting, never thought of this. Could be improved by something like `self.template_code = self.template_code or template_code`, in `TemplateColumn.__init__()`, but you still need to define the class attributes before the call to `super()`. So your original question won't work with my suggested improvement either.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I tried your "edit" suggestion and now I get `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'template_name'`.  I have a workaround for now, so no worries.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The error is because you are passing template_name to your DeleteColumn (probably in a different class). To resolve it it depends if you want to hard-code the template_name or not. If yes then just do a kwargs['template_name'] = 'wakemeup/admin/delete_link.html' before calling init and pass *args and **kwargs to it. If you don't want to hard-code it but leave it as a default value then check if template_name exists in kwargs and if not set it to kwargs before calling __init__.